# Recursive value in a function

Tags: vb.net, function, recursion

I am trying to develop a simple class-based function that will modify a previous value determined by the function, that is, it is a recurrence relationship.

In essence, I am developing my own random number generator which will work the same way the current Random class works, i.e.

```
Dim ran as New Random(123456)
For i = 0 To 9
   MessageBox.Show(ran.NextDouble & "  " & ran.Next(1,11))
Next
```

I can successfully do this using a class-based method simply by sending a value ByRef, but as you know for a method call, the old value to be modified needs to be placed inside the call to the method.  Thus, I am trying to overcome use of a method or a global typed variable, and rather would like the instantiated class to somehow remember what the current value is.

The example code below attempts to multiply the value `_value` by 2 during every function call, so the expected result would be 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.  However, even though a 2 is initially sent to the constructor, the value of `_value` is always returned as zero.

```
Class Example
    Public _value As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal _value)

    End Sub
    Public Function Value() As Integer
        _value *= 2
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As New Example(2)
    For i = 0 To 9
        MessageBox.Show(x.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You have class-level variable `_value` which never gets assigned in the constructor. You also have the parameter variable `_value` in the constructor, which should be changed to `value`. Then, in the constructor, add the line `_value = value`.

Comment: _even though a 2 is initially sent to the constructor, the value of _value is always returned as zero._ .... Because you don't set the passed value in the constructor. You should `Me._value = _value`. Use a different param name to avoid using `Me`.

Comment: I believe recursion usually involves a method that calls itself. I don't see any recursive action here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally fields are `Private`. If you want to expose data from your class you would use a `Public Property`.

Change the name of the parameter for `Sub New`. If properly qualified your name will work but it is confusing. You must do something with the passed in value! Assign it to your field `_value`.

Your Function has no return value. It simply changes the value of `_value`. If you don't return anything use a `Sub`. Change the name of your `Function` to something meaningful. Add a `Return` statement to send a value back to the calling code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As New Example(2)
    For i = 0 To 9
        MessageBox.Show(x.DoubleValue.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Class Example
    Private _value As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal Input As Integer)
        _value = Input
    End Sub
    Public Function DoubleValue() As Integer
        _value *= 2
        Return _value
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: In your Example class above, how could a `_count` variable be used to track the number of times `DoubleValue()` was called?  For my needs, `_count` would not need to be returned, but would need to be incremented and memorized every time `DoubleValue` is called.   I would also need to be able to reset `_count = 0` inside the Example class any time e.g. `_count=1000.`

Comment: Do you want the count for the life of the class? The instance of the class falls out of scope at End Sub of the button click. You could keep a Form level variable which you increment every time you call the function and reset at 1000 checking with an if statement.

Comment: Yes, life of the class.  Already tried a public variable and incremented it inside `DoubleValue`, but wondered if there was a way to make `_count` behave like it's global, the same way `_value` behaves like it's global, but was never declared at the Form level, or Public global declaration.

Comment: You can make a class level variable in the Example class and increment in the function. Be aware the value will disappear as soon as the End Sub in the click even is reached. The Example class instance is declared inside that Sub.

Comment: Can you answer this new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230642/creating-a-simple-one-dimensional-sobol-sequence-generator ?  It works out that 99% of the recursive numbers are generated by an iterator function, but the goal would be that you only want one number at a time, just like a `.NextDouble` function call to .NET's random number generator.